# Dot character negation in mysql regex search

Tags: mysql, regex, regex-negation

I want to use a regualr expression in a mysql search that macth a string and NOT the same string followed by a dot . character.
As an example i want to match the product code 3.4.5.1 but not 3.4.5.1.4 I have a workaround using a double like :

```
SELECT *  from mytable  where myclolumn like '%3.4.5.1%' AND mycolumn NOT like '%3.4.5.1.%'....
```

Not a very elegant solution.
So I was trying to use  `REGEXP_LIKE(mycolumn,'(3.4.5.1)[^\.]')`

In fact I have tested that pattern and works nicely in php and even online : https://regexr.com/66olc
but seems that regex works in their own way in MYSQL because I obtain an empty search result.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you looking specifically for `"3.4.5.1"`?  Or any string of single digits?  Or can they be multi-digit, such as "34.7654"

Comment: Product codes are strings of group of digits (normally one or two) separated by dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
([^0-9]|^)3\.4\.5\.1([^.0-9]|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yy4Svp/1). *Details*:

- `([^0-9]|^)` - a non-digit char (`[^0-9]`) or (`|`) start of string (`^`)
- `3\.4\.5\.1`  - `3.4.5.1` literal string (dots in regex must be escaped with a literal backslash to match a `.` char, else, `.` matches any single char)
- `([^.0-9]|$)` - any char other than a `.` and digit (`[^.0-9]`), or (`|`) end of string (`$`).

Comment: FYI: If that does not work as expected in the target environment, you might need to double the backslashes.

Comment: VERY interesting! Thanks! Seems working also in mysql. Using a capture group you can avoid escaping the dots in fact the core of my error was not putting the OR END OF STRING and the capture group around the dot negation : '([^0-9]|^)(3.4.5.1)([^.]|$)' works also

Answer (score 0):

"Groups of digits separated by dots":

```
([0-9]+[.])+[0-9]+
```

Explanations:

```
[0-9]+  -- 1 or more digit; you could change "+" to "{1,2}" to say "1 or 2"
[.]     -- a single dot; this would work, too:  \.
(...)+  -- 1 or more of what's between the parens
```